# okhttp3 websocket dynamic header

Tags: java, android, websocket, okhttp

I'm trying to create a websocket and dynamically recalculate its header in every message sent. Is it possible?

I was trying to use an interceptor but is only called once.

```
public void run() {

    // only open a websocket if there aren't websockets already open
    if (this.webSocket == null || !this.openingWS) {

        this.openingWS = true;

        wsBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        OkHttpClient client = wsBuilder.addInterceptor(this)
                .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("wss://...")
                    .build();


        client.newWebSocket(request, this);

        // Trigger shutdown of the dispatcher's executor so this process can exit cleanly.
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }
}

@Override public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
    this.openingWS = false;     // already open
    this.webSocket = webSocket; // storing websocket for future usages
    if (listener != null) listener.onWSOpen();
}

public void sendCommand(String cmd) {
    System.out.println("SEND " + cmd);
    if (webSocket != null) webSocket.send(cmd);
}
```

This same class is implementing the interceptor

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request originalRequest = chain.request();

    if (!isSpecial()) return chain.proceed(originalRequest);

    okhttp3.Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("text", "...")
            .addHeader("dfds", "...");


    Request compressedRequest = builder.build();

    return chain.proceed(compressedRequest);

}
```

The authentication code sent in the header will change every X seconds/minutes.
If it's not possible to change dynamically the header, what is the best way to approach this kind of connection?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the headers are send only first time when you request the connection, later is depends on frames between the client and the server.

So if you want to inform the server that you had changed the header then send message with your new header. Or you can close the connection and start a new one with the new header.